# jQuery Datepicker Beforeshowday two arrays of dates

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, datepicker

I have one array for disabled dates and another for dates to be highlighted. Is there a way to code this?

e.g.:

```
beforeShowDay: function(date){
    var unavilble = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('yy/mm/dd', date);
    var newstring = [ arrayable.indexOf(unavilble) == -1 ];
    return newstring;
    },
```

2nd array:

```
var datet = ['2014/01/19', '2014/01/20'];
        //tips are optional but good to have
var tips  = ['some description','some other description'];      

function highlightDays(date) {
    for (var i = 0; i < datet.length; i++) {
        if (new Date(datet[i]).toString() == date.toString()) {              
            return [true, 'highlight', tips[i]];
        }
    }
    return [true, ''];
 } 
beforeShowDay: highlightDays,
```

Comment: can the same day be there in both the arrays

Comment: check http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Den5V/2/

Comment: whether one of the array will be a subset of another one

Comment: hi Arun, it worked as below, but they may have crossover of days but ill fix that before going into the function :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like

```
var datet = ['2014/01/19', '2014/01/20'];
//tips are optional but good to have
var tips = ['some description', 'some other description'];
var arrayable = ['2014/01/01', '2014/01/08', '2014/01/15', '2014/01/22', '2014/01/29']
$('input').datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'yy/mm/dd',
    beforeShowDay: function (date) {
        var datestring = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('yy/mm/dd', date);
        var hindex = $.inArray(datestring, datet);
        if (hindex > -1) {
            return [true, 'highlight', tips[hindex]];
        }
        var aindex = $.inArray(datestring, arrayable);
        return [aindex == -1]
    }
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Den5V/)

Comment: Hi Arun. I tried your code it is working as is but it isn't working with an array which is dynamically populated. Don't know why? It is highlighting all the dates on the calendar. Any ideas?

Comment: The problem could be the format of the values in the array

Comment: @ArunPJohny this line of code `ar datestring = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('yy/mm/dd', date);` don't format the date? Or I should have to do it separately then provide it the formatted date?

Comment: No it isn't working even after providing it the exact same format that is used in above code. :(